# Does Intel HD graphic support open gl 2.0 uand up?

Tags: windows

Hello I am Timothy I want to create a 3d app in unity but I want to use Blender to create a 3d character but blender needs OpenGL 3.0 and up, if OpenGL 3.0 is not supported how about OpenGL 2.0 because I am also an aviation enthusiast so I want to try X-plane 11 but it needs OpenGL 2.0 so does intel HD graphics supports it

Comment: "Intel HD Graphics" covers a multitude of versions of graphics processor. To know which version you have we would need to know what processor you have.

Comment: I have intel i3 540 3.07Ghz Processor

Comment: Could you [edit] that into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/46473/intel-core-i3-540-processor-4m-cache-3-06-ghz.html) your i3 540 is a Clarkdale processor core.

This uses, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Gen5), an Ironlake GPU.

From the table on that Wikipedia article the GPU is DirectX 10.1 and OpenGL 2.1.

If what you want to do only uses OpenGL 2.0 then you should be fine, but integrated graphics can be quite quirky at times.